# How to model creation and completing a targeted Quiz in DDD Style

Tags: domain-driven-design

I want to model a system where someone is creating Quiz and he can choose who should do the quiz. When submitted the invited people have a deadline to solve the quiz and the creator and maybe some other guys have the authority to see the status of each Invitee, whether they finished it or not. (Basically it is kind of a Knowledge Quiz to check your employees have the know how or need more training, thus not every Quiz is needed for everyone but only for selected people)

I have an Aggregate Quiz which contains the questions and answers. It has of course commands to create a Quiz and update it. But I am not sure about the part where the Invitees need to solve the Quiz. Should this be modeled as another Aggregate? Or would I have in the same Quiz Aggregate a command like
`complete(invitee: Invitee)`? Or is the the 'solving a Quiz' part another bounded context and should be treated like that, thus creating another concept of Quiz (without the update and create commands) in that bounded context but have commands like complete or fail?

Another approach I could think of is when the creator submitted the Quiz (created it) then a new Aggregate for each Invitee is created referencing the Quiz and the Invitee and a status whether it is complete or not. The reason I thought of that is because when I have one Aggregate that tracks all Invitees status, then it would need to always load all that data each time I want to do something with that Aggregate (e.g. run the command `complete(invitee:Invitee)`).

I am using Event Sourcing in my system, so technically I would need to store the Event
`QuizCompleted(quizID, inviteeName)`. But I dont know which Aggregate would store this event

What would be a good design for the Aggregates and their relationship?